# Laravel Test on controller returning uncorrect status code

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to create a test on a rest API using Laravel. My test is in 3 steps : Arrange, act and assert. 
During the first step I create an entry in the database. For the second test i query my DB, finally i check if the tests are true or not.

```
use RefreshDatabase;

/** @test */
public function createTest() {
    // Arrange : name & message OK
    $message = ChatMessages::create([
        'username' => 'My name is long enough',
        'message' => 'my message is also OK'
    ]);

    // Act
    $getAllMessages = ChatMessages::all();

    $this->post('/message', $message->toArray())
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertExactJson([
            'status' => 'ok', 'chat_message' => $message->toArray()
        ]);


    // assert : if name too short, data is not persisted
    $this->assertEquals(sizeof($getAllMessages), 1);
}
```

My route :

```
Route::post('/message', 'ChatController@create');
```

I have the following error message :

Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that false is true.

In my Controller I have this code :

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
        'message' => 'required|string|min:1',
    ]);

    try {
        $message = ChatMessages::create([
            'username' => $input['username'],
            'message' => $input['message'],
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $err) {
        Log::error("Cannot fetch chat messages");
        Log::error($err);
        abort(500);
    }

    return response()->json(['status' => 'ok', 'chat_message' => $message]);
}
```

$request->validate should give a 302 redirection if not satisfied and 200 if OK.

Comment: Why are you creating a ChatMessage inside your Test Case before calling Controller Method?

Comment: I create an entry and test if i obtain expected result ... I query the database and expect to have 1 entry.. I should do it differently ?

Comment: You should not create the entry in Table manually. You should call `$this->post()` and pass appropriate data and then check if the entry was inserted successfully in the Table. This way you know that your code in controller is working fine.

Comment: it doesn't explain : Expected status code 200 but received 404.

Comment: Use `$this->withExceptionHandling();` at the top of your method. It will give you a better explanation of the error.

Comment: I do think i have issue with my url ... Its solved : 
$this->post('/api/message', $message) ... I think I should type more often route:list